# Calcium chloride hexahydrate has separated in jar - is it beyond saving?

Tags: inorganic-chemistry, teaching-lab

I work in a lab where I'm in charge of ordering new supplies. A graduate student brought up a $500~\mathrm{g}$ amber jar of $\ce{CaCl2.6H2O}$ and pointed out that it had separated into a clear liquid (on top) and a white crystal (on bottom). The cap seemed to be on normally and there is no expiration date on the jar.

Before I decide if I need to order more, I am wondering:

- What happened to the $\ce{CaCl2}$?
- Can it be saved?

Comment: Welcome to Chemistry.SE! Take the [tour] to get familiar with this site. Mathematical expressions and equations can be [formatted](http://meta.chemistry.stackexchange.com/q/86/4945) using $\LaTeX$ syntax. While it may seem strange at first we do not use salutations in our Questions and Answers. Please use the upvote button to say thanks, or leave a comment how the post can be improved. I assume that the packaging was not sealed? It would further be good if you include your thoughts on the matter.

Comment: It likely just drew water from the atmosphere.

Comment: Can't see why recrystallization wouldn't help it

Answer (score 2):

Calcium chloride is incredibly hygroscopic (it sucks in water), this property makes it incredibly useful (for instance when used in a desiccator or in a drying tube to prevent water from getting into a reaction).

The wet $\ce{CaCl2}$ can be turned back into a solid  by heating (ideally under vacuum), however you can end up with a mixture of different compounds (for instance heating very wet $\ce{CaCl2}$ has been known to give $\ce{Ca(OH)2}$).  It can also be recrystallised from ethanol to give the di-hydrate, which in turn may be dehydrated by heating, however fresh $\ce{CaCl2}$ is very inexpensive, and so I would suggest buying a new bottle, and ensuring it is sealed well after use to prevent it taking up moisture from the atmosphere.

Comment: Note that OP’s jar was apparantly labelled $\ce{CaCl2 . 6 H2O}$

Comment: "purification of laboratory chemicals" only gives details of anhydrous $\ce{CaCl2}$ or the di-hydrate. I assume that the hexahydrate is the lowest grade available as a solid. In any case, the advice holds: recrystallisation may work, but its probably cheaper and easier to buy new material. Heating is an option but may lead to degradation into a mixture.

Answer (score 1):

As others have said, $\ce{CaCl2}$ is absolutely spiffing in drawing water from where-ever. You might have the cap firmly on the jar but humidity probably found its way in, just because the screwing of the cap was not enough to completely seal away the outer atmosphere. The relative humidity in that jar will be *very* low so entropy will draw ever more water inside. It is not that uncommon for $\ce{CaCl2}$ to end up in the middle of a puddle of water drawn.

It depends on what you want to do with the stuff whether you can still use it.

- If you just need calcium chloride and don’t care about specifics: Go for it!
- If you just need hydrated calcium chloride: Go for it!
- If you need to weigh a semi-exact amount of hydrated calcium chloride: Filtration should be enough.
- If you want to do some real sensitive analysis that requires exact stoichiometric amounts of $\ce{CaCl2}$ you need to get a new one or recrystallise to a defined hydrate.
- If you wanted to use $\ce{CaCl2}$ as a drying agent: Why the heck are you even considering the hydrate?

Then again, the stuff is cheap, so if you feel safer, buy a new one. Don’t chuck the old one, though, it can most certainly be put to good use!